# Collection to string() convertion in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm a beginner.my question is,
I have an observablecollection(of string)

How can I add those collection's each elements as an array of string elements 
Using for loop?

```
Dim obsv as new observablecollection(of string) // has some collection of string

For each str in obsv

// How can I add that str into string Array

Next
```

Comment: why not just call `ToArray()` method on the collection?

Comment: Just a side question. Do you need to learn VB.NET? Microsoft is making it more and more redundant. Would C# be an option?

Comment: @Enigmativity, Agree. I'd advise anyone who is starting learning VB.NET to switch to C#.

Comment: VB is a perfectly cromulent language, with a significant base of software that will require ongoing maintenance.  I'd also tend to think that it's a bit more accessible to learn, and so it might be a better gateway to .NET than C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ `.ToArray()` method. Or use the `Item[Int32]` property.

```vb
Dim s As ObservableCollection(Of String)
' Whatever code to fill that collection.

' First solution:
Dim arr1 = s.ToArray() ' This needs the System.Linq namespace to be imported.

' Second solution:
Dim arr2(s.Count - 1) As String
For i As Integer = 0 To s.Count - 1
   arr2(i) = s.Item(i)
Next
```

And here is a complete working code snippet:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim s As New ObservableCollection(Of String)()
        s.Add("Hello")
        s.Add("World")
        ' Whatever code to fill that collection.

        ' First solution:
        Dim arr1 = s.ToArray() ' This needs the System.Linq namespace to be imported.
        Console.WriteLine("First array:")
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", arr1))
        Console.WriteLine()

        ' Second solution:
        Dim arr2(s.Count - 1) As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To s.Count - 1
            arr2(i) = s.Item(i)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Second array:")
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", arr2))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output is:

```
First array:
Hello, World

Second array:
Hello, World
```

Or if you want to use For Each loop, you can do it like that:

```vb
Dim arr2(s.Count - 1) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each str In s
    arr2(i) = str
    i += 1
Next
```